# How to make material ui active tab on specific route

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am trying to figure out how to deal with this issue I am having with Material UI tabs. So I have a navbar with three different tabs. They all link to different url's but two of them are kind of similar in a way. Please see my code below:

```
<Tabs indicatorColor="primary" value={this.state.tabsValue} onChange={this.setTabsValue}>
                    <Tab className={classes.tab}
                      label="Main"
                      value="main"
                      component={Link}
                      to="/main"
                      classes={{ selected: classes.selectedTab, }} />
                    <Tab className={classes.tab}
                      label="Shoes"
                      value="shoes"
                      component={Link}
                      to="/sale/shoes"
                      classes={{ selected: classes.selectedTab, }} />
                    <Tab className={classes.tab}
                      label="Sale"
                      value="sale"
                      component={Link}
                      to="/sale"
                      classes={{ selected: classes.selectedTab }} />
                  </Tabs>
```

Here is where setTabsValue is handling change events:

```
  setTabsValue = (obj, val) => {
    this.setState({
      tabsValue: val
    });
  };
```

And when there is a prop change, the setTabsValue is being set also here:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const newRoute = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    if (this.state.tabsValue !== newRoute) {
      // update currentRoute for user ping
      this.currentRoute = newRoute;
      this.setState({
        tabsValue: this.isMainRoute(newRoute)
      });
    }
```

As you may notice, the last two tabs have a common point where the word 'sale' is in the destination route. This caused an issue where if I were to try to visit shoes, the active tab underline would be under the sale tab. Im not sure what is causing the issue but my guess it has something to do with the routes being similar for the last two tabs.

Basically the only way where the active tab underline will show under 'Shoes' tab is when I am already on 'Sale' tab and I click 'Shoes'. After a prop update,(maybe after a few seconds) it will go back to the 'Sale' tab, which is weird.

Not sure what is going wrong here but any help is appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are familiar, but React Router is a great solution for this that I use in all of my projects. https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

The following is an example of how you would go about making an application that would route you to components for each page.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```